# Asks password when trying to install Boot-Repair

Tags: boot, grub2, password, sudo

I'm trying to install Boot-Repair directly from Lubuntu, but after typing the line "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair" in the terminal (as suggested here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), he asks the sudo password. I type my own password (no * or other character appears while typing) but continues asking. What can I do?

Comment: do you used image iso or dd when you created a bootable pendrive? Because when i do with a dd image this problem happened, but if you create how a iso image this problem can solve. Well, for my problem was a solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type your pw (no * symbols appear - this is default!) and hit enter, it should either accept it or give you a mesage like "That did not work, please try again" and repeat the procedure three times. After that you should be back at your cli prompt.
If sudo behaves like I just described, you typed the wrong password. This can have mainly one of the following reasons:

- You just don't remember your correct pw or have a simple typo in it
- Your CAPS LOCK key is on
- Or you Num L0ck key
- Or something changed your keyboard layout
- Maybe you set a password for the root user?

So to start, type your pw into the normal terminal window to see if all characters are entered correctly (eliminates reasons 2,3,4).
Then log out and back of your account with that password to be 100% sure it is the corrct pw for your account.
At last we would have to check that root's pw is disabled... But this only if the simple things don't work.
Let me know if one of these options helped you. Greetings and good luck!

Comment: Done. The problem was the bloc num was active when I set the password so it didn't get a number. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that I could help you! But as you're a new user, you might not know that in this forum, question posters should [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer, if it solves their problem. This will a) mark the question as solved, and b) give me and you a nice [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) bonus. So to accept my answer, just click on the gray tick on left of it so that it becomes green - finished. Thank you for participating on AskUbuntu! :-D

Comment: Good one! ;-) (and an upvote)