# How to change forgotten password without bios ?

Tags: 14.04, password, kde

When I logged in today on my laptop and tried to do something in konsole it asked me for my password. So i typed in my password like 100 times and it keeps on saying that It's incorrect. It worked yesterday and I know for sure I didn't change it. Is there any way to change it or make it work ? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)  doesn't work for me. I have toshiba chromebook 2 and I don't have bios so this method doesn't work ! When I type sudo su to get root access Its asking me for username password which doesn't work. I tried to do it in chrome os by pressing `ctrl+alt+t` and then `shell` this is what I get.

`chronos@localhost / $ sudo passwd
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: Authentication token lock busy
passwd: password unchanged`

so I tried different method.

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo su
localhost / # sudo passwd
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: Authentication token lock busy
passwd: password unchanged
localhost / # sudo passwd crazy_driver
passwd: unknown user crazy_driver
localhost / # passwd crazy_driver
passwd: unknown user crazy_driver
```

Again: `chronos@localhost / $ sudo passwd crazy_driver
passwd: unknown user crazy_driver`

I don't know why would it say unknown user, maybe because Im not logged in to chroot ? but if i log in its asking for password before I get to make any changes.
Can anyone help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Please look at my answer about passwords [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/580249/367990) before starting with the complicated steps. Sometimes the solution is so easy that it is easy to oversee... If not, give me a ping and we will look what we can do.

Comment: I tried all that before writing the question. Password worked since I set it up and today its wrong ?.There is no such thing like capslock or numlock in my keyboard either.

Comment: You don't need to have a BIOS for that answer. You hold [Shift] key _after_ the BIOS/UEFI/manufacturer logo screen to make the GRUB menu appear (if you don't get into it by default). There you select "recovery mode" and proceed as described. Why should that do not work?

Comment: Do you have chromebook too ? I press shift when developers mode is on and nothing and I press shift after that when chrome logo shows and still nothing.  I don't think it works on my chromebook

Comment: No, no Chromebook. That's strange... Can't you see any possibility to enter GRUB menu? You might check out how to reconfig GRUB from within Ubuntu to unhide the boot menu... But you would need sudo for that :P - so you might have to boot a live Ubuntu and chroot into your installation.

Comment: so basically I would have to reinstall ubuntu ?

Comment: NO! Just boot from a live DVD or USB stick (you would also use to reinstall it) and select "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install...". Mount the partition you actually have Ubuntu installed on and access the GRUB config file `/etc/default/grub`. Note that this is not the absolute path, but the relative one to the partition mountpoint! Do not access the one of the life system - that would be useless. Google for the HIDDEN_TIMEOUT options, I am not sure how exactly that worked. Set it up so that you will see the GRUB menu at boot.